# Managed package installation is very slow for a customer

Tags: managed-package, metadata-api, scheduled-apex, timeout

For one of our customers, we see that it takes unusually long to install a managed package using the Metadata API. The package has a few classes and custom fields. We receive a read timeout after 5 minutes. The package finally installs in about 8 minutes. The usual customer install is about 30 seconds.

Apart from background jobs/ apex jobs / scheduled jobs, what other processes can slow down managed package installation. We have tried by disabling some of the scheduled apex jobs without luck.

Would appreciate any pointers/ suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this is purely related to the size of the package, the type of org and number of tenants on the same instance that this org is on (and what they are doing).

Remember that Salesforce provide different capabilities (including performance profiles) for different types of org and that many orgs execute on the same server(s) as if they were virtual machines.

In my experience, nothing you do on the org is likely to change how long the install takes. This depends on the size of the package and the resources available for the installation at the time. If other orgs on the same instance are busy, there will be fewer resources available, so the install will take longer.